# fonts corrupted in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts

Tricky problem here. For some reason, the default font in Chrome has changed itself to Arial Black (or Arial Narrow - can't really tell) and won't change back. I've tried altering the Chrome font settings, and resetting Windows fonts to default, to no avail. It only seems to be affecting Chrome, not firefox.

Here's what my typical webpage looks like right now:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XCGG.png

Ideally, I'd hope to fix this w/o going through the hassle of a full reinstall (I have a lot of bookmarks).

Comment: When did the problem appear? Did you install another browser/application?

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: I installed a website picture grabbing app for Chrome, but I have since unsintalled it.

Comment: the dev tools? for this page?

Comment: Yes. Press F12 and investigate which is the font type.

Comment: font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; < body fonts

Answer (score 0):

Go To :
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets
And add following 2 lines in Custom.css

@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; src: local('Arial'); }
@font-face { font-family: 'helvetica neue'; font-weight:bold; src: local('Arial'); }

This worked for me.